# Import a XML file to postgres, why $body$ error?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sync_from_xml()
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    myxml    xml;
    datafile text := 'path/to/my_file.xml';
BEGIN

myxml := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 100000000);
```

This function returns error

> ERROR:  unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$

. How do I solve it?

Comment: is it the whole code?.. please post error as well

Comment: It is the whole code... error is string delimited from dollars not terminated

Comment: You are missing an `end` for the function body.

Answer (score 2):

the definition is not completed, yo uneed to terminate it, eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sync_from_xml()
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    myxml    xml;
    datafile text := 'path/to/my_file.xml';
BEGIN

myxml := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 100000000); 

END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

here `$BODY$` is a safe quote - function definition remains inside quotes

Comment: CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS
SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) x;

Comment: please don't debug in comments - if you meet problem you can't solve after reading docs and googling - post a new question